# How to run the same exe file twice using subprocess in Python

Tags: python, api, python-requests, exe

I am new to using APIs. I need to run the same exe file twice at the same time and use API calls to communicate with each one. When I want to run the exe file just once, I follow these steps to communicate with it

```
import subprocess
import requests

command = "App.exe --restserver"
subprocess.Popen(command)

server_address = "127.0.0.1:5000"

end_point = "/load/"

parameters = {
  "type" = "designI"
}

url = "http://" + server_address + end_point

response_load_designI = requests.post(f"{url}", parameters)
```

Now I want to run App.exe again but load *`"designII"`* this time while I still have *`"designI"`* up and running. I am wondering what will be the server address for the 2nd time I run App.exe? Is there a way to force the 2nd run to use a different address? I tried in two terminals to run them separately but in both terminals I got the same server address (`'127.0.0.1:5000'`).

Comment: you have to define the url it uses within the `App.exe` itself. That way you can either pass it as an argument, or something else

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh Thnx for the prompt comment. Could you elaborate your answer? Does this mean some modifications inside ```App.exe```? Or adding the url as part of the ```command```?

Comment: Well I don't know what your `App.exe` is, so I can't help much. But if it were a `flask` server for example, you would set your desired url as a parameter. So you'd have to have `App1.exe` with one url, and `App2.exe` with another one.

Comment: The supporting document coming with ```App.exe``` says that "A REST API based on a FLASK REST Server is supported".

Comment: That means you can run one instance, doesn't help with the second one. You still need to define somewhere what the second url is supposed to be.